# ¿Cómo rellenar una tabla que tengo en otro fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, tablas

**Fragment 1**

```
TableLayout tableLayout;
```

Tengo esta variable table layout.

```
tableLayout = (TableLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.TabLayout_resumen);
final resumen resumen = new resumen();
```

Inicializada de esta manera.

```
String cadena[] = {"1","Gol","Dan"};

TableRow row = new TableRow(getActivity());

TextView textView;

for(int i = 0; i<resumen.header.length;i++){
    textView = new TextView(getContext());
    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    textView.setText(cadena[i]);
    row.addView(textView);
}
tableLayout.addView(row);
```

Con este código quiero rellenar la tabla con ID **TabLayout_resumen** que está en otro fragment.

**Fragment 2**

```
tabLayout_resumen = (TableLayout)views.findViewById(R.id.TabLayout_resumen);
        
tabladinamica tabladinamica = new tabladinamica(tabLayout_resumen,getActivity());
        
tabladinamica.addHeader(header);
```

Answer (score 0):

Al iniciar el Fragment puedes "pasar" parametros por medio de un bundle

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putStringArrayList("nombre_del_argumento", miListaEnString);
MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
fragment.setArguments(args);
fragment.show(fragmentTransaction, "tag_del_fragment")
```

Y utilizarlos en tu nuevo fragmento de la siguiente manera

```
ArrayList<String> miLista = getArguments.getStringArrayList("nombre_del_argumento");
// ... AJUSTAR AL LLENADO DE LA TABLA
```